# $f(n)=O(g(n))$ implies $f(n)^2=O(g(n)^2)$

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics

I have trouble proving that $f(n)=O(g(n))$ implies $f(n)^2=O(g(n)^2)$.
I was thinking about using the definition
$$f(n) \leq c \cdot g(n)$$ and then just
$$f(n)^2 \leq c^2 \cdot g(n)^2$$
But that doesn't seem to be correct.

Comment: _Why_ does that seem wrong to you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your intuition is right, you just need to verify it rigorously.

The definition gives
$$\begin{align}
|f(n)| \le Cg(n) \implies |f(n)|^2 &\le Cg(n)|f(n)| \\&\le Cg(n)\cdot Cg(n) \\&= C^2g(n)^2\end{align}$$
Hence, $f(n)^2 = O(g(n)^2)$.

Comment: Thank you, I had a feeling I did it 'too fast' as this way I could also prove something that isn't true, that's why I had doubts.

Comment: You can make it shorter, as any midschooler knows one can multiply  inequality involving only nonnegative numbers.

Comment: @Bernard And this is what I did... just multiplied by $|f(n)|$.

Comment: @VIVID: I saw that, but you forgot the absolute value, which ensures the condition on signs is satisfied.